Proof that the Countable Product of Standard Borel Spaces is Standard Borel
This question is about Theorem 2.3 of chapter V in K. R. Parthasarathy's Probability Measures
on Metric Spaces (1967), which states that if $ (X_n, \mathcal{B}_n) $, $ n =
1,2,\ldots $ are standard Borel spaces, $ X := \prod_{n \geq 1} X_n $ and
$ \mathcal{B} = \bigotimes_{n \geq 1} \mathcal{B}_n $ denotes the product of the
$\sigma$-algebras $ (\mathcal{B}_n)_{n \geq 1} $, then $ (X, \mathcal{B}) $ is
also standard Borel. The proof starts by asserting that we can assume each $ X_n
$ to be Polish with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $ \mathcal{B}_n $ without loss of
generality. I don't see why this is true.

For reference: a standard Borel space is defined in Definition 2.2 of the same book as a
countably generated space $ (X, \mathcal{B}) $ for which there exists a Polish
space $ Y $ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $ \mathcal{B}_Y $ such that the
$\sigma$-algebras $ \mathcal{B} $ and $ \mathcal{B}_Y $ are $\sigma$-isomorphic. The
concept of a $\sigma$-isomorphism is defined at the end of the second paragraph
before Def. 2.2 as a bijection $ \tau\colon \mathcal{B} \rightarrow
\mathcal{B}_Y $ which preserves countable set operations.  This is weaker than
in the usual definition of standard Borel spaces (e.g. in A.  Kechris' Classical
Descriptive Set Theory, §12.B), where $ \tau $ must be an isomorphism (i.e. a
bimeasurable bijection) from $ (X, \mathcal{B})$ to $ (Y, \mathcal{B}_Y) $.
For the stronger definition from Kechris, it is clear how to proceed:
Each $(X_n, \mathcal B_n)$ being countably  generated implies the same for their countable product $(X, \mathcal B)$. Next, if for each $n \in
\mathbb{N}$, $ \tau_n $ is an isomorphism from $ (X_n, \mathcal{B}_n) $ into a
Polish $ (Y_n, \mathcal{B}_{Y_n}) $, then the product map
\begin{equation}
    \prod_{n  \geq 1} X_n \ni (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \mapsto
    (\tau_n(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \prod_{n  \geq 1} Y_n
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism from $ (X, \mathcal{B}) $ into $ (\prod_{n \geq
1}^{} Y_n, \bigotimes_{n \geq 1}^{} \mathcal{B}_{Y_n}) $. The latter space is
Polish, hence $ (X, \mathcal{B}) $ is standard Borel. But if we merely have a
family of $\sigma$-isomorphisms $ \tau_n\colon \mathcal{B}_n \rightarrow
\mathcal{B}_{Y_n} $, $ n \in\mathbb{N} $, how do we get a $\sigma$-isomorphism $
\tau\colon \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \bigotimes_{n \geq 1}^{} \mathcal{B}_{Y_n} $?

First, for clarity, I shall say two measurable spaces $(X, \Sigma)$ and $(Y, \Omega)$ are isomorphic if there is a bimeasurable bijection $\tau: (X, \Sigma) \to (Y, \Omega)$, and say they are $\sigma$-isomorphic if there is a $\sigma$-isomorphism $\tau: \Sigma \to \Omega$. Now, for a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$, we define the indistinguishability equivalence relation $\approx_\Sigma$ on $X$ by letting $x \approx_\Sigma y$ iff, for all $A \in \Sigma$, $x \in A \Leftrightarrow y \in A$. Let $q_\Sigma: X \to X/\approx_\Sigma$ be the quotient map. Note that the pushforward $\sigma$-algebra $(q_\Sigma)_\ast\Sigma$ is naturally $\sigma$-isomorphic to $\Sigma$.
Proposition: Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Then the following are equivalent:

$(X, \Sigma)$ are $\sigma$-isomorphic to a Polish space (with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra);
$(X/\approx_\Sigma, (q_\Sigma)_\ast\Sigma)$ is isomorphic to a Polish space (with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra).

Since $(q_\Sigma)_\ast\Sigma$ is $\sigma$-isomorphic to $\Sigma$, $2 \Rightarrow 1$ is obvious. To prove $1 \Rightarrow 2$, we need a few lemmas:
Lemma 1: Let $(X, \mathcal{B})$ be a Polish space and its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then there exists a sequence $F_n$ of subsets of $\mathcal{B}$ s.t.,

$F_n$ is countable for every $n$;
$\bigcup F_n = X$ for every $n$;
If $A_n \in F_n$ for each $n$, then either $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \varnothing$, or $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is a singleton.

Proof: Fix a countable dense subset $\{x_k\} \subset X$. Then let,
$$F_n = \{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x_k): k \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
where $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x_k)$ is the closed ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ around $x_k$. Condition $1$ is obviously satisfied. Density of $\{x_k\}$ directly implies condition $2$. For condition $3$, let $A_n \in F_n$ for each $n$. We note that, as the diameter of $A_n$ is at most $\frac{2}{n}$, we have the diameter of $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is $0$, i.e., it is either empty or a singleton. $\square$
Lemma 2: Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space, $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be a Polish space with its $\sigma$-algebra, $\tau: \Sigma \to \mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-isomorphism. Then $X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$.
Proof: Let $F_n \subset \mathcal{B}$ be as given in Lemma $1$. Pick any $x \in X$. Since $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-isomorphism, $F_n$ is countable, and $\bigcup F_n = Y$, we have $\bigcup_{K \in F_n} \tau^{-1}(K) = X$. Hence, for each $n$ there exists $K_n \in F_n$ s.t. $x \in \tau^{-1}(K_n)$. There are now two possibilities,

$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n = \varnothing$. As $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-isomorphism, this implies $\varnothing = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \tau^{-1}(K_n) \ni x$, a contradiction.
$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ is a singleton $\{y\}$. But, again as $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-isomorphism, this implies $\tau^{-1}(\{y\}) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \tau^{-1}(K_n) \ni x$.

As $x \in X$ is arbitrary, this means $X \subset \bigcup_{y \in Y} \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. The converse is obvious. $\square$
Lemma 3: Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space, $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be a Polish space with its $\sigma$-algebra, $\tau: \Sigma \to \mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-isomorphism. Then for any $A \in \Sigma$, $A = \bigcup_{y \in \tau(A)} \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$.
Proof: Since $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-isomorphism, we have, for any $y \in \tau(A)$,
$$A = \tau^{-1}(\tau(A)) \supset \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$$
so $A \supset \bigcup_{y \in \tau(A)} \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. To prove the converse, let $x \in A$. By Lemma $2$, there exists $y \in Y$ s.t. $x \in \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. Hence, $A \cap \tau^{-1}(\{y\}) \in \Sigma$ is a nonempty subset of $\tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. So as $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-isomorphism,
$$\varnothing \neq \tau(A \cap \tau^{-1}(\{y\})) = \tau(A) \cap \{y\}$$
Thus, $y \in \tau(A)$. As $x \in A$ is arbitrary, this implies $A \subset \bigcup_{y \in \tau(A)} \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. $\square$
Proof of $1 \Rightarrow 2$ in Proposition: Let $\tau: \Sigma \to \mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-isomorphism where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some Polish space $Y$. By Lemma $2$, for each $x \in X$ there is a $y \in Y$ s.t. $x \in \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$. Note that, if $y_1 \neq y_2$, then as $\{y_1\} \cap \{y_2\} = \varnothing$, we have $\tau^{-1}(\{y_1\}) \cap \tau^{-1}(\{y_2\}) = \varnothing$. Thus, the $y \in Y$ for which $x \in \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$ is unique, and we shall denote this $y$ by $f(x)$, so $f: X \to Y$ is a well-defined function. We note that it is surjective. Indeed, for any $y \in Y$, $\{y\} \neq \varnothing$, so $\tau^{-1}(\{y\}) \neq \varnothing$, and any $x \in \tau^{-1}(\{y\})$ will satisfy $f(x) = y$.
We claim that, if $x_1 \approx_\Sigma x_2$, then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Indeed, $\tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\}) \in \Sigma$ and contains $x_1$, so $x_2 \in \tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\})$ and therefore $f(x_2) = f(x_1)$. Conversely, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 \approx_\Sigma x_2$. Assume to the contrary that $x_1 \not\approx_\Sigma x_2$. Then WLOG we may choose $A \in \Sigma$ s.t. $x_1 \in A$ but $x_2 \notin A$. As $x_1 \in \tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\})$, we have $A \cap \tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\}) \in \Sigma$ is nonempty, so $\tau(A) \cap \{f(x_1)\}$ is nonempty and hence $\{f(x_1)\} \subset \tau(A)$. Applying $\tau^{-1}$, this yields $\tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\}) \subset A$. But $f(x_2) = f(x_1)$, so $x_2 \in \tau^{-1}(\{f(x_1)\}) \subset A$, a contradiction.
This shows that $f: X \to Y$ induces a bijection $\tilde{f}: X/\approx_\Sigma \to Y$. We claim that $\tilde{f}$ is bimeasurable to finish the proof. Indeed, let $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Then $B = \tau(A)$ for some $A \in \Sigma$. By Lemma $3$ and definition of $f$, we immediately see that,
$$q_\Sigma^{-1}(\tilde{f}^{-1}(B)) = f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(\tau(A)) = A$$
So $\tilde{f}^{-1}(B) \in (q_\Sigma)_\ast\Sigma$ and $\tilde{f}$ is measurable. Conversely, let $\tilde{A} \in (q_\Sigma)_\ast\Sigma$. Then $A = q_\Sigma^{-1}(\tilde{A}) \in \Sigma$ and $\tilde{f}(\tilde{A}) = f(A)$. Again from Lemma $3$, it is easy to show that,
$$\tilde{f}(\tilde{A}) = f(A) = \tau(A) \in \mathcal{B}$$
so $\tilde{f}^{-1}$ is measurable as well. $\square$
It is relatively easy to conclude the proof from this point onward. Only one more lemma is needed. Its proof is somewhat tedious but straightforward, so I’ll just leave it as an exercise (though I’ll add the details if requested):
Lemma 4: Let $(X_i, \mathcal{B}_i)$ be a collection of measurable spaces, then for $(x_i), (y_i) \in \prod_i X_i$, we have $(x_i) \approx_{\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}_i} (y_i)$ iff $x_i \approx_{\mathcal{B}_i} y_i$ for all $i$. Furthermore,
$$((\prod_i X_i)/\approx_{\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}_i}, (q_{\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}_i})_\ast\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}_i) \simeq (\prod_i (X_i/\approx_{\mathcal{B}_i}), \bigotimes_i ((q_{\mathcal{B}_i})_\ast\mathcal{B}_i))$$
Combining Proposition, Lemma $4$, and the standard fact that a countable product of Polish spaces is Polish (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the product space coinciding with the product of Borel $\sigma$-algebras), we obtain the desired result.

Thanks for the fantastic answer! Does Lemma 4 really hold for arbitrary measurable spaces? For the isomorphism between the quotient of the product and the product of the quotients, I took $ f\colon (\prod_i X_i)/\approx_{\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}i} \ni [(x_i)] ↦  ([x_i]) ∈  \prod_i (X_i/\approx{\mathcal{B}i})$. I managed to show that $f$ maps measurable sets in $ (q{\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}i})\ast\bigotimes_i \mathcal{B}i $ to measurable sets in $ \bigotimes_i ((q{\mathcal{B}i})\ast\mathcal{B}_i)$ only under the added assumption that each $\mathcal B_i$ is countably generated.

@jro Admittedly I didn’t write down all the details myself, but I’m pretty sure countable generation is not needed? Countable generation is needed to prove atoms are measurable, but that fact is not needed in the proof that $f$ is an isomorphism. You can begin by proving $f$ is a bijection. Then $\bigotimes_i((q_{\mathcal{B}i})\ast\mathcal{B}i)$ is generated by sets of the form $q{\mathcal{B}{i_0}}(A)\times\prod{i\neq i_0}(X_i/\approx_{\mathcal{B}i})$, where $A\in\mathcal{B}{i_0}$. Then we have…

@jro … $f^{-1}(q_{\mathcal{B}{i_0}}(A)\times\prod{i\neq i_0}(X_i/\approx_{\mathcal{B}i}))=q{\bigotimes_i\mathcal{B}i}(A\times\prod{i\neq i_0}X_i)$ and sets of the latter form generate $(q_{\bigotimes_i\mathcal{B}i})\ast\bigotimes_i\mathcal{B}_i$, so $f$ is a bimeasurable bijection. (While atoms may not be measurable, it is still the case that every measurable set is a disjoint union of atoms, so all the quotient maps $q$ commute with taking unions, intersections, and complements, so far as all the sets involved are measurable.)

I now see. Many thanks again!
